# Designing Java Objects from Magento JSON

Tags: java, json, magento, gson

Below are the raw JSON string returned from Magento REST API call:

```json
{  
   "1":{  
      "entity_id":"1",
      "website_id":"1",
      "email":"john.oliver@hbo.com",
      "group_id":"1",
      "created_at":"2015-04-21 12:47:00",
      "disable_auto_group_change":"0",
      "prefix":null,
      "firstname":"John",
      "middlename":null,
      "lastname":"Oliver",
      "suffix":null,
      "taxvat":null,
      "created_in":"Admin"
   },
   "2":{  
      "entity_id":"2",
      "website_id":"1",
      "email":"beck.johnson@yahoo.com",
      "group_id":"1",
      "created_at":"2015-04-21 13:40:48",
      "disable_auto_group_change":"0",
      "prefix":null,
      "firstname":"Beckie",
      "middlename":null,
      "lastname":"Johnson",
      "suffix":null,
      "taxvat":null,
      "created_in":"Admin"
   }
}
```

I would like to construct the POJO for the first time and here are the classes:

```
public class Customers {

    private Map<String, Customer> customerMap;

    public Map<String, Customer> getCustomerMap() {
        return customerMap;
    }

    public void setCustomerMap(Map<String, Customer> customerMap) {
        this.customerMap = customerMap;
    }
}

public class Customer {
    private String entity_id;
    private String website_id;
    private String email;
    private String group_id;
    private String created_at;
    private String disable_auto_group_change;
    private String prefix;
    private String firstname;
    private String middlename;
    private String lastname;
    private String suffix;
    private String taxvat;
    private String created_in;
    public String getEntity_id() {
        return entity_id;
    }
    public void setEntity_id(String entity_id) {
        this.entity_id = entity_id;
    }
    public String getWebsite_id() {
        return website_id;
    }
    public void setWebsite_id(String website_id) {
        this.website_id = website_id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getGroup_id() {
        return group_id;
    }
    public void setGroup_id(String group_id) {
        this.group_id = group_id;
    }
    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }
    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
    public String getDisable_auto_group_change() {
        return disable_auto_group_change;
    }
    public void setDisable_auto_group_change(String disable_auto_group_change) {
        this.disable_auto_group_change = disable_auto_group_change;
    }
    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }
    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getMiddlename() {
        return middlename;
    }
    public void setMiddlename(String middlename) {
        this.middlename = middlename;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }
    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }
    public String getTaxvat() {
        return taxvat;
    }
    public void setTaxvat(String taxvat) {
        this.taxvat = taxvat;
    }
    public String getCreated_in() {
        return created_in;
    }
    public void setCreated_in(String created_in) {
        this.created_in = created_in;
    }

}
```

Then, I tried using `Gson` to do the parsing:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Customers customers = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), Customers.class);
System.out.println(customers.getCustomerMap());
```

But the result is `null`.

I am suspecting the class format might be wrong, can anyone suggest what's the right format? The number `1` and `2` at the beginning of each set are automatically generated by Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work by default because Gson expects to have a field named `"customerMap"` in order to use the default deserialization. The easiest (**NOT NECESSARILY BEST**) solution would be to simply do this:

```java
String jsonText = "{\"customerMap\":"+response.getBody()+"}";
Customers customers = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Customers.class);
```

By adding the field name around the outside of your mapping, Gson knows what to do, and the `println` will output, for instance:

```
{1=Customer@2f56a6be, 2=Customer@61dd1c39}
```

However, it would be better to write a [custom deserializer for your Customers class](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1298/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html), or to modify the output of Magneto to add the surrounding `{"customerMap":` and `}`

---

**Do NOT try to do this**:

```
Map<String, Customer> cust = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Map.class);
```

This will *actually* generate a `Map` of type `Map<String, LinkedTreeMap>`, where `LinkedTreeMap` is an internal gson class.

Comment: It works wonderfully on the first "NOT NECESSARILY BEST" method.

Custom deserialiser is too much hassle because the scope of implementation is very narrow. Don't expect much to change and very limited objects for conversion.

Modifying Magento output is impossible because this is a third party integration code. 

Many thanks.